# 3D : Given 2 points (P0, P1), find the third point (P2) where DotProduct(P0P2, P1P2) == 0

Tags: 3d, space, points

Sorry for my bad english.

Do you know the best (in performance) algorithm to find the solution of the problem in the Title. 
As a reminder, the problem is :
Given 2 points (P0, P1), find the third point (P2) where DotProduct(P0P2, P1P2) == 0
[image]

To solve this problem I'll do the following :

- The distance P0P1 (dist(P0, P1)) is known. So i retrieve two equations with pythagore : dist(P0, P2)² + dist(P1, P2)² = dist(P0, P1)²
- I retrieve two other equations with dot product : DotProduct(P0P2, P1P2) = 0
- Finally, I solve the system with 4 equations and 3 variables

But I think there is a more efficient solution.

Can you help me ?

Thank you :)

PS : I am working in Space (3D)

Edit : As ja72 said, I forgot to add constraints... So Here is the problem in its entirety :
[image]
I have P0 and P0' which define the local X axis of an object (P0 is the center of the object).
I also have P1 which I must use to find P2 so the line P0P2 defines the local Y axis of this object.
P1 is orthogonal to P0P0'.

Comment: There are infinite points in 3D the locus of which creates a sphere. If you draw a diametrical circle from P0 to P1 along _any_ plane through P0 and P1 then any point on the circle is going to make a 90° angle (as shown above).

Comment: You are right.   It's a piece of a bigger problem and I removed one constraint I should not.

Comment: Try to use some formatting (like `Dot(A,B)`) for better readability.

Comment: Thank you ja72. I edited my post to contain all the problem.  
And also, thank you for the formatting, I will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, there needs to be more constraints in order to define a single unique point. In fact, you need 2 more constraints.

The problem is shown below:

[image: pic]

Take any plane which contains P0 and P1. Draw a circle with P0 and P1 as diameter points. **Any** point along the circle is going to have `DOT(P0-P2,P0-P1)==0` by default. See [Thale's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales'_theorem).

**Edit 1**

The problem is defined now as decomposing the relative position of `P1` to `P0` along the `x` axis and finding the perpendicular `y` such that

```
P1 = P0 + a*x + b*y
```

where `a` and `b` are distances defined below. Each `P1`, `P0`, `x` and `y` is a 3D vector with `(x,y,z)` values.

1. Define the relative vector `r = P1-P0`
2. Find the distance `a = Dot(r,x)/Dot(x,x)`
3. Find the point `P2 = P1-a*x`
4. Find the distance `b=Magnitude(P2-P0)`
5. Find the unit vector `y=(P2-P0)/b`

Done!

[image: pic2]

<sub>NOTE: `x` does not need to be a unit vector, but it helps in order for the value `a` to correpsond to the actual projected distance between `P0` and `P1`.</sub>

Comment: Yes you are right. I'am editing right now my post with constraints :)